# How do you get a copy of the current series array instance in react-apexcharts / apexcharts?

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I'm trying to get access to the current series array in react-apexcharts including data series items which have been toggled on/off, so I can loop through and set new a data series (seriesPercentage) based on the existing series instance, and update like this:

```
ApexCharts.exec("historic", "updateSeries", seriesPercentage);
```

Comment: Maybe try doing this on `legendClick` event https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/events/#legendClick. There you have `seriesIndex` and `config` which contains series

Comment: Hi Patryk, I'm creating a custom legend so trying to access the series outside of the options, but thanks anyway.